# How to integrate morris js graph into my ng 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, morris.js

I'd like to use Morris Js plugin in my angular 2 project? I know how to create the morris.js chart in html page. But I don't know how to integrate Morris chart to my ng 2 app. How can I do it?

I get this, when I run component.html file:

[image: I get this, when I run component.html file]

I want to load graph in here:

[image: I want to load graph in here]

Comment: There is no morris charts package for angular 2 project even "angular-morris" is a package for angularJS. If you want rich chart library for angular 2 projects I introduce "C3.js" and "nvd3.js"

Comment: This package exists https://github.com/mika-el/angular-morris-js and works well!